# inserting CLOB after setinputsizes() raises illegal variable name/number

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have an oracle table that I'm trying to insert lots of data (mostly long strings) from a csv into.

I have found that I need to use the CLOB data type for my strings, as they often exceed 4000 characters. I have also found that I need to use the 'setinputsizes()' function or I run into 'ValueError: string data too large'.

But somehow, using 'setinputsizes()' breaks my insert queries, and I get 'ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number'?

Example:

```
create_query = "CREATE TABLE sequences (myid varchar(10), allele varchar(50), seq clob)"
cursor.execute (create_query)
cursor.setinputsizes(seq = cx_Oracle.CLOB)
insert_query = "INSERT INTO sequences (myid, allele, seq) VALUES ('00001;', 'HLA-A*01:01:01:01', 'CGCTGACCTGTG')" # seq truncated; in truth it's much longer hence the CLOB type
cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

Without the 'setinputsizes()' line, the above query executes fine - but when I use the real value for seq, which exceeds 4000 characters, it fails with

```
DatabaseError: ORA-01704: string literal too long
```

But with the 'setinputsizes()' line, I get

```
DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

(Note: I know that executemany is better for bulk inserts. But I get the same errors there, so am trying to solve this problem first.)

Can anyone tell me whatm doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the `DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number` is in the wrong calling of `setinputsizes()`.

The correct line should be

```
cursor.setinputsizes(None, None, cx_Oracle.CLOB)
```

because `setinputsizes()` needs to be set for all bound variables at once (in the right order!), not separately.

This needs to be combined with positional binding of the values to be entered, or else there's a `DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`.

The working code looks like this:

```
create_query = "CREATE TABLE sequences (myid varchar(10), allele varchar(50), seq clob)"
cursor.execute (create_query)
cursor.setinputsizes(None, None, cx_Oracle.CLOB)
insert_query = "INSERT INTO sequences (myid, allele, seq) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)" # seq truncated; in truth it's much longer hence the CLOB type
cursor.execute(insert_query, ['HLA00001;', 'HLA-A*01:01:01:01', seq])
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

When inserting or updating a `CLOB` with a string literal that exceeds 4,000 characters (or bytes) you need to assign that string literal to a PL/SQL variable, and then insert or update that table in a PL/SQL block.

Example:

```
DECLARE
    l_seq CLOB;
BEGIN
    l_seq := 'CGCTGACCTGTG.....CGCTGACCTGTG';

    INSERT INTO sequences (myid, allele, seq) VALUES ('00001;', 'HLA-A*01:01:01:01', l_seq);
END;
/
```

Comment: This helps with the `string literal too long` error, and with your code the single queries execute fine for long and short seqs. However, since the individual values for seq vary greatly, I then ran into the problem described [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-oracle/mailman/message/25693506/). It turns out, the central problem of my code was wrong calling of `setinputsizes`. Using that properly makes the code work without the PL/SQL block. I have added a separate answer that covers this. Thanks for teaching me some PL/SQL, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01704: string literal too long` means that the query you send to the database cannot be correctly parsed because there is some identifier which is too long.
This identifier can a table name, column name, function name (max length 30 byte).

Also make sure there is no escaping problem with your `seq` column (a `'` occurring in the string which is not escaped).